# Get taxonomy term by slug in post on archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a registered a custom post type called "projects" and assigned a taxonomy called "disciplines". Here's how it looks:

```
<?php
// Register projects cpt
function projects() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Projects', 'Post Type General Name', 'sitename' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Project', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'sitename' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Projects', 'sitename' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Projects', 'sitename' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'sitename' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'sitename' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'sitename' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'sitename' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'sitename' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'sitename' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'sitename' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'sitename' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'sitename' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'sitename' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'sitename' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'sitename' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'sitename' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'sitename' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'sitename' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'sitename' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'sitename' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'sitename' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'sitename' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'sitename' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'sitename' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'sitename' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'sitename' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Projects', 'sitename' ),
        'description'           => __( 'A custom post type for projects.', 'sitename' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'disciplines' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-appearance',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'projects', 0 );

// Register disciplines taxonomy
function disciplines() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Disciplines', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'sitename' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Discipline', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'sitename' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Disciplines', 'sitename' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'sitename' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'sitename' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'sitename' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'sitename' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'sitename' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'sitename' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'sitename' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'sitename' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'sitename' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'sitename' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'sitename' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'sitename' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'sitename' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'sitename' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'sitename' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'sitename' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'sitename' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'disciplines', array( 'projects' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'disciplines', 0 );
```

I've then created an `archive-projects.php` page, like so:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package sitename
 */

get_header();
?>
<div class="has-sidebar">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main">

            <article class="navy">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <header class="entry-header screen-reader-text">
                        <h1>Projects</h1>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <div class="button-group filters-button-group narrow" id="filters">
                        <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button>

                        <?php
                            // Loop through categories - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories
                            $categories = get_categories( array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'disciplines',
                                'orderby'  => 'name',
                                'order'    => 'ASC'
                            ) );
                            foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                                echo '<button class="button" data-filter=".'.$category->slug.'">';
                                echo $category->name;
                                echo '</button>';
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="entry-content filter" id="images">

                        <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>

                        <?php
                            // Loop through posts
                            while ( have_posts() ) :
                            the_post();

                            // Get post ID - Important for pulling ACF fields from single posts
                            $post_id = get_the_ID();

                            // Get post terms
                            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'disciplines' );

                        ?>

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="filter-item <?= $terms->slug; ?>" data-category="<?= $terms->slug; ?>">

                                <figure>
                                    <?php
                                        if ( get_field('thumbnail_image', $post_id) ) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('thumbnail_image', $post_id), 'medium-square');
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('hero_image', $post_id), 'medium-square');
                                        }
                                    ?> 
                                </figure>

                                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                            </a>

                        <?php
                            endwhile;
                        ?>

                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                    <?php
                        else:
                            echo '<p>Please add some projects.</p>';
                        endif;
                    ?>

            </article>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- .has-sidebar -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm trying to get the taxonomy term by slug for each post class and data attribute, but the method I've used isn't working. I've followed [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) as a guide.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code, the function wp_get_post_terms() return an array of WP_Term objects, so you can't access directly to an object property without specifying an index for the array like :

```
$terms[0]->slug
```

Otherwise, you should iterate through the whole array of terms and retrieve the slug into an another array, like :

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'disciplines' );
    $terms_slug = [];
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $terms_slug[] = $term->slug;
    }
```

And finally, you can implode the all the gathered slugs into your class attribute :

```
class="filter-item <?= implode(' ', $terms_slug); ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was going around in circles on this. Using `$terms[0]->slug` worked perfectly.